# Stack overflow when using regular expression on java styled comments

Tags: regex, performance, stack-overflow

I'm currently writing a parser in Scala, where I want to have my whitespace defined as matching on both whitespace, and java styled `/* */` comments. I don't need the `//` part.

Currently I'm using this definition:

```
"""((\s+)|(?:/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*/]))*\*+/))*""".r
```

I have found most of this definition on this page:
http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html

The problem is that I'm getting a stackoverflow when matching my input. However adjusting my stacksize up to 1 mb fixes the problem. This is unfortunately not a possibility in my production system.
So what I'm asking for, is if somebody could help me improve my regular expression?

Help would be much appreciated, since I'm only a novice in the Regex world:)

Thanks in advance.

Regards Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `normal* ( special normal*) *` pattern for comments. You'll need multiline matching.

Here, `special` is `*` not followed by a `/` and `normal` is anything but `*`. Unquoted, regexes are

- special is `\*(?!/)`;
- normal is  `[^*]`.

I don't know scala, but you need to define one var for special, one var for normal, use:

`/\*<normal>*(<special><normal>*)*\*/`

and this will swallow your white spaces without a fear of stack overflow.